# How to use database object of parent class in php

Tags: php, inheritance

i have the following code

```
class Application
{
    protected $db;
    public function getDBChange(database $db)
        {
            $this->db =& $db;
                $this->update($db);
        }
protected function update($db)
    {
        $this->db=& $db;
        echo "\nServer - update- IN";
        $SQL = "UPDATE `version` SET app_ver='1.0.6'";

        if (!$this->db->query($SQL))
        {
            echo "\nDatabase Error.";
        }
        echo "\nServer - update- OUT";
    }
}
```

it works properly but when I called this update function from a child class it gives error the child class as follow

```
class DemoApplication extends Application
{
    callParent()
    {
        $this->update($this->db);
    }
}
```

when i use this way it gives Error `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in`

Comment: `database $db` works properly ?

Comment: thank for reply tried but doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `$db` doesn't have a `query()` method. Is `$this->db` actually set and of an object that has a `query()` method?

Do some debugging:

```
var_dump($this->db);
```

Comment: if db hasn't a query method then how it successfully execute from parent class

Comment: I'm just rephrasing the error. Like I said, try debugging the `$db` value, and you'll see that it doesn't actually have a `query()` method.

Comment: it properly works from the same class but when i called from a child class it gives error so no doubt about the $db or query()

Comment: Yes, so start debugging it, because `$db` is not what you think it is. Just do it and stop arguing with me ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried `var_dump`'ing it yet? You'll probably find that it's not an object but rather a string or integer.

Comment: `object (path)#2 (1) {
  ["error_text"]=>
  NULL
}` from parent class and `NULL` from child class

Comment: Like I said, `$db` isn't set properly.

Comment: ya i found where `$bd` gets null

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing `$this->db` to a method in a same `$this` context? Why not just set `$this->db` in a child class and then call `$this->update`? Since they are both defined in a parent class there should be no problem doing this. As for error itself: you try to set private member with address assignment of external variable, therefore it is possible to access a private member of an object later on via variable you want private member address to.